# offset colorbox position in Facebook page app

Tags: jquery, colorbox, facebook-javascript-sdk

Finding myself in a bit of a corner - I'm trying to use colorbox on a Facebook page app, and am having problems due to the iframe.

Colorbox usage, which works fine but loads in the middle of the frame:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.popup').colorbox();        
});


<a class='popup' href='xxxxxx' title='title'><img src='xxxxxx'/></a>
```

I can get the scrollTop value from the FB api and send that to Colorbox, along with a string of html:

```
$("a.popup").click(function () {
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function (fbCanvasInfoObject) {
        var fbPosition = fbCanvasInfoObject.scrollTop;
        $.colorbox({html:"content", pxToTop:fbPosition});
    });
})
```

With a small change in Colorbox to use the pxTotop value, which sets the modal window 150px from the top of the viewport:

```
top = settings.pxToTop + 150;
```

I need to combine the two, and have the Colorbox functionality from the first example (the standard functionality with the image title showing as the caption), combined with the offset generated in the second example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always happens - ask a question, then find the answer myself. If anyone is interested, solution is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.popup").live("click", function () {
        var caption = this.title;
        var image = this.href;
        FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function (fbCanvasInfoObject) {
            var fbPosition = fbCanvasInfoObject.scrollTop;
            $.colorbox({ href:image, title: caption, fbScrollTop: fbPosition });
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

Modified the Colorbox script (~ln518):

```
var top = settings.fbScrollTop + 150;
```

Sorted. Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your contribution. It really work for one image :)

I have another issue on the group image by clicking next or previous.

Thanks,